# Postfix maillog: warning: host nb-mx-vip1.prodigy.net[207 .115.36.20]:25 greeted me with my own hostname

Tags: postfix, firewall, smtp, fedora

Mail server on internal system, reachable through a gateway / firewall via forwarded port returned this error.

I upgraded my environment (unadvisedly) with Fedora Core 19 and have had lots of networking problems, and this was one of them. I researched it thoroughly. All the articles I've seen (12+) have been for the circumstance when the target domain is actually supposed to be served by the system logging the error.  This is NOT that circumstance; ANY outbound email returned this error (and sent a rejection reply to the sender, which in this case is always local).

I figured it out already and it has a VERY non-obvious cause. I'm taking the time to "leave breadcrumbs" for others. The question is: What can cause this, when one has every reason to believe the configuration is correct?!

Sep 25 07:53:54 server1 postfix/smtp[9531]: warning: host nb-mx-vip1.prodigy.net[207
.115.36.20]:25 greeted me with my own hostname mail.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispte the fact that one interface's address is non-routing and another's is routing, the new firewalld puts BOTH in the public zone and masquerades both of them.

The solution is to run ifconfig to discover which interface is which, and then plug the internal interface's name into the following commands where they presently read 'em1':

> firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --remove-interface=em1
>   firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-interface=em1
>   firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-interface=em1 
>   firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-interface=em1

It's quite non-obvious this configuration error on firewalld's part would cause this problem, but it does...

Comment: FirewallD is very new and strange, and I don't recommend using it in production (yet).